# Symfony show EventListener changes in Form

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I use Symfony 3.4 and doctrine and have a problem with data changed by an Event Listener.

If a form is submitted and a Doctrine PreUpdate EventLister changes an entity value, this is not visible in the form.

Example with an entity called Activity which has an attribute $number:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="activity")
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"ActivityListener"})
 */
class Activity
{
  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  private $number ;

  ...
  Getters, Setters an other stuff...
}
```

And an Event Listener:

```
class ActivityListener
{
  // Events
  public function get()
  {
    return ( ['preUpdate']);
  }

  public function preUpdate(Activity $activity, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
  {
    $activity->setNumber(1) ;
  }
}
```

Form processing in the controller, assuming that I submitted the form with e.g. 0 as value for my number field:

```
class ActivityController
{
  ...
  // Create form and handle request
  $form = $this->createForm (ActivityForm::class, $activity) ;   
  $this->form->handleRequest ( $this->request ) ;
  if ( $this->form->isSubmitted() )
  {
    // $activity->number == 0 as entred in HTML Form
    $this->em->persist($activity) ; 
    $this->em->flush();
    // $activity->number == 1 as set in PreUpdate Event
  }
  $this->view = $this->form->createView () ;
  ...
}
```

So the "number" field is correctly set to 1 by the EventListener and saved correctly to the database.

But the Form is rendered with "0" in the number field, probably because the values are already fetched with the createForm command?

How can I achive that the new value, which my Event Listener has written to the entity, is shown correctly in the form?

Thank you and kind regards,
Sascha

Comment: So you want to value to be 1 already when it is shown in the form?

Comment: Yes, that is right. The form is submitted with the field containing the value 0. In the entity the value is set to 1 in the preUpdate Event and this value is saved to the database. So the form should contain the value 1, then.

Answer (score 0):

the `preUpdate` event happends after the form is submitted, that's why in the form, the 0 is still showed.

If you want it to be 1 already, a `preUpdate` event is not what you should use. You could update it manually, or set 1 as default value in the form field.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In reality my problem is a bit more complex - I just reduced the sample code to make it less verbose. In the form there is a list element. Depending on the list selection another field is set according to a corresponding database query. So in my preEvent trigger there is a condition like "if list selection = 1 then get $value from database", "if list selection = 2 then get another $value from database". So I need the submitted form data to determine the new $value and I want to display this new $value in the form, so the user may change it if he wants to.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem. After saving the entity I just recreate the form, so it contains the modified values.

Roughly like this in the controller that handles the form submitting:

```
$this->form->handleRequest ( $this->request ) ;
if ($this->form->isValid() )
{
  // Persist data 
  $this->em->persist($this->entity) ;
  // At this point, entity data has been modified by PreUpdate Event
  $this->em->flush();
  $this->flashbag->add ( 'success', $this->translator->trans('form.info.save') ) ;

  // Recreate form so the modified data is instantly shown in the form
  $this->createForm (EntityForm::class, $entity ) ;
  $this->view = $this->form->createView () ;
}
```